# c# run a thread each one minute despite the thread time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I want to run a process every one minute, but I have been told that the `Timer` is working every `x minute + the time required for the process to finish`. but I want the thread to work every `1` minute even though the thread process may keep working for 1 hour.

I hope you got me, so in the final image, I may have 10 threads working together.

is that possible ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you not using TPL and tasks? The overhead of Tasks is minimal.

Comment: besides: what do you mean by running a "Process" every minute? You have threads and since 4.0 tasks. To start a new process you have Process.Start("example.txt");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the timer. Simple test shows that `System.Threading.Timer` works the way you want:

```
var timer = new Timer(s => { "Start".Dump(); Thread.Sleep(10000); "Hi!".Dump(); }, 
                      null, 1000, 1000);

Thread.Sleep(20000);

timer.Dump();
```

The callback executes every second even though it takes ten seconds to execute.

This is basically because the callback for this particular timer is simply posted to the threadpool, while e.g. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is actually tied to the UI thread. Of course, if you simply start a new thread (or queue work, or start a new task etc.) in the callback of winforms timer, it will work in a similar (albeit less precise) way.

Using the right tool for the job usually makes things much easier :)

Comment: +1 because this uses the thread pool instead of creating a new thread, of course using Tasks is best ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Well, of course - if you just exit your program, it will kill all the background threads. In a real program, you'd want to wait for a shutdown signal or something like that instead - this depends entirely on what kind of application you've got. And `Dump` is there just for debugging purposes, you don't need that at all. Just make sure the reference to `timer` stays alive (e.g. in most cases you don't want it as a local variable :)).

Comment: @Luaan thanks for your explaining. I need to build an app that keep (forever) doing something, could you update your question please? in other words, I need even 20 seconds to do something, every 20 seconds, for the whole life. now this is my code `var timer = new Timer(s =>
            {
                Printing.check();
            },
                      null, 1000, 1000);
            Thread.Sleep(20000);` where `Printing.check()` is the thing that I want to keep executing every 20 seconds for the whole life

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli That means you probably want to make a windows service. In that case, just create the default service using Visual Studio, and just add the timer to the designer. That should work pretty much out of the box :)

Comment: @Luaan exactly a windows service, that is what I am doing, you are a genuis. are you saying that there is a way to create a windows service from visual studio 2012 ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Well, yeah. Just do New Project -> Visual C# -> Windows -> Windows service. Then just add the timer to the service designer, set the timeouts, events etc. and that should pretty much be it.

Comment: @Luaan I drag and drop `Timer` from the toolbar to the designer, then what should I do please in order to tell the timer to work every 20 seconds, and to do the `PritingCheck` function call? +1 I will accept your answer, but please keep help me

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Note that you need to use the `System.Timers.Timer` version, not `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Just set the `Interval` property to `20000`, and set the `Elapsed` event to whatever code you want to run.

Comment: @Luaan what I find in the toolbar is `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, is there a toolbar object for the `System.Timers.Timer` or I need to create it in the code?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli You can add it to the toolbar - right click the toolbar, select `Choose items...` and add the other timer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Timer and on the elapse event just fire a new thread to do the work, like the below example:

```
public class Example
{
    private static Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program... ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
    }

    public static void DoWork()
    {
        var workCounter = 0;
        while (workCounter < 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alpha.Beta is running in its own thread." + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            workCounter++;
        }
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the thread object, passing in the method
        // via a delegate.
        var oThread = new Thread(DoWork);

        // Start the thread
        oThread.Start();
    }


}
```

Comment: The new thread will start after 2000 msec + thread creation time which is not insignificant (thread stack creation etc.)

Comment: You could always use System.Threading.Timer instead, it has a constructor where you can indicate when the first time the event should be raised.

Comment: This won't change the fact that the `var oThread = new Thread(doWork)` is quite costly and adds to time ...

Comment: That is a good point, However A task returned by Task.Run() is rather saying that you want to execute the code separately. But the task scheduler will determine when the task will be executed. In the end it depends what @marco-dinatsoli wants. If it doesn't matter at what time the work is finished and you don't need any control over the execution, but want the result. Go definitely for Task, if you want to be able to Have more control over the created thread (abort/suspend/etc.) go for thread.

Answer (score 1):

Since .NET 4.0 Tasks are preferred to Threads.
The overhead of Task management is minimal.

```
// Create a task spawning a working task every 1000 msec
var t = Task.Run(async delegate 
{ 
    while (isRunning)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Task.Run(() => 
        {
            //your work
        };
    }  
});
```